# Has Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource dropped support for Channels?

Tags: event-log, system.diagnostics, etw, etw-eventsource

I've just upgraded my service to use the latest NuGet ETW package, previously using the beta version. However, it seems channel support has been dropped from the event source.

Does anyone have an idea what has happened here?

Comment: I'm running 1.0.16 using channels, it might be a namespace issue if you are using System.Diagnostics.Tracing instead of Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.

Comment: Hi, I think I had some problem with my NuGet packages not getting updated correctly.